# Position a div relavtive to another div: SVG issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an id="div_Diagram" that contains two other divs, div_CanvasHeader and div_Canvas, as shown. div_Canvas also contans an SVG, which in turn contains several rects. Each rect has is constructed in a way that its has a javascript script attached to its mouseover event with the x & y position values passed into the script.
[image]

Do to the nature of svgs, I'm not able to correctly position the tooltip division relative to the rect. I'd like to be able to use the rect coordinates (x&y) to position the tooltip relative to div_CanvasHeader or div_Diagram.  Other then x & y, all other dimensions are fixed.

Here is the javascript.  (Note that the tooltip is a telerik control. The Show() method does show the tooltip with all of the correct content but at the bottom left of page).

```
function showSVGTtip(elt, x, y) {

        if (elt.hasAttribute("name")) {

            var ttipText = elt.getAttribute("ttipText ");

            var ttip = $find("<%=myToolTipDiv.ClientID %>");

            document.getElementById("ttipLabel").innerHTML = ttipText ;
            ttip.show();

            // Need to set position of ttip relative to other element such as pnlCanvasHeader
        }
    }
```

How do I position the tooltip div relative to one of the other divs? For example, if I have the id of the tooltip div, can I move it on the client relative to div_CanvasHeader?  Does the tooltip need to be contained within the other div?

Comment: It may be simpler to position your tooltips absolutely inside their parents if your tooltip plugin doesn't facilitate positioning by coordinates. I don't see where you tell us what you're using.

Comment: It's currently a Telerik tooltip, but I'd be willing to change that. I've tried working with them on this but with no success. Because they couldn't attach to the svg rect directly, they suggested I just find a javascript method.